# Accidentally sent BCH to BTC address... I tried to use the private keys in a BCH wallet to recover, and there's no coins showing

Tags: bitcoin-cash, copay, cross-chain-recovery

I've read many other threads like this and it seems to be the common consensus that to recover BCH sent to a BTC address, just use the private key inside a BCH compatible wallet. Well, I did that, and there are no coins showing, nor the address that I originally sent the BCH to (which has 100+ confirmations already).

Not really sure what to do in this case. The wallet which I originally sent the BCH to was a Bitcoin wallet in the Copay app.

Comment: Is it a segwit address?

Comment: @RaghavSood, it was legacy I believe, but I don't see how that's relevant, because there are no filled addresses at all in my BCH or BTC wallets related to this private key. I know the private key is valid because I've used it for BTC many times before, and usually keep it empty. It's just, when I load this private key under both BCH and BTC wallets, they're all totally empty. Yet, the address itself, which was generated by Copay from this private key, is showing a received BCH transaction.

Comment: Segwit matters because it does not exist on the BCH network. If it is a segwit address, you need to reach out to a miner such as BTC.com to get the coins back safely. Do you have a txid?

Answer (score 1):

To recover Bitcoin Cash (BCH) from a Bitpay/Copay BTC wallet, please follow the steps below:
1. Within the Bitpay/Copay app, navigate to `Settings`
2. Select the desired Bitcoin wallet then tap on `More Options`
3. Tap on the `Duplicate ( Bitcoin Cash )` option

Duplicating the BTC wallet will create a BCH wallet in your BitPay or Copay app with the BCH balance.

The option above to `duplicate` is not available for multi-sig BTC wallets, and you will need to use the [recovery tool](https://bitpay.github.io/copay-recovery/) to recover BCH funds sent to a multi-sig BTC wallet.

Then, please clear your history cache. To do so, please open up your BitPay app and do the following steps:

- `Settings` > `Wallet` > `More Options` > `Transaction History` > `Clear cache`

And finally, scan for addresses.

- `Settings` > `Wallet` > `More Options` > `Wallet Addresses` > `Scan addresses for funds`